# Dovecot Install: "/usr/lib/dovecot/imap: No such file or directory"

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have set up postfix and am now attempting to set up dovecot. I did `apt-get install dovecot-common`
I have changed *dovcot.conf* to include the following

```
protocols = imap imaps
```

And I now get this error when restarting dovcot

> Error: mail_executable: Can't use /usr/lib/dovecot/imap: No such file
>   or directory Fatal: Invalid configuration in /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

Did I install the wrong package, is there another package I need, or am I missing something else ?

Thanks.

Comment: ignore me, I should have read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot

Comment: Could you add an answer to your post explaining what you did to resolve this?

Comment: To use dovecot as IMAP server you have to install `dovecot-imapd`. `dovecot-common` includes just the files used by both the IMAP and the POP3 servers but not the ones used by just one of them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To cite [Florian Diesch](https://askubuntu.com/users/2369/florian-diesch)s comment:

You have to install not only the `dovecot-common` package, but the `dovecot-imapd` package as well (`dovecot-pop3d` as option if one wants to propose access over POP3).

To cite [NimChimpsky](https://askubuntu.com/users/210/nimchimpsky)s comment:

For further informations about the installation of Dovecot, read more on [help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot).

Answer (score -1):

For me this worked (Ubuntu 22.04):

```
sudo apt purge dovecot-core dovecot-imapd
```

and then

```
sudo apt install dovecot-core dovecot-imapd
```